# Convert number that is in factor type to date

Tags: r

I have a date frame below that has date converted to factor as shown below

```
   df 
   ColA    ColB   
    a      43191
    b      43192
    c      43193
```

I need below dataframe which third column that is converted to date.

```
  df 
   ColA    ColB    Dateconverted
    a      43191    01-04-2018
    b      43192    02-04-2018
    c      43193    03-04-2018
```

I tried with the below code but did not work

```
  df$Dateconverted <- as.Date(df$ColB,origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: does `as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(df$ColB)), origin = "1899-12-30")` work??

Comment: perfect thanks.............